# How to accept PayPal payments in a Python application?

Tags: python, online-payment

How to accept PayPal payments in Python?

Particularly what about recurring/subscription payments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django Debits](http://freesoft.portonvictor.org/django-debits.xml) is an advanced Python payment receiving framework.

Django Debits has particularly great support for recurring/subscription payments.

It is available both open source and commercial version.

Support for the following advanced features:

- support for both regular and recurring transactions
- support for imitating a subscription payment with any number of manual payments for any paid duration placed whenever the customer wants
- automatic disallowing duplicate payments of the same invoice
- support for automatic cancellation of old subscription as soon as a new subscription is placed by the customer
- sending reminder emails, with customizable templates
- trial period without registering at the payment processor (such as PayPal) site and without asking a credit card
- subscription period and trial period can be any numbers of days, weeks, months, years (subject to payment processor limitations)
- very customizable, for example the example application shipped with the project shows the following features

  - several pricing plans
  - easy subscription and unsubscription
  - switching between pricing plans at any time (subject to PayPal limitations)
  - calculation and automatic adjustment of the remaining time to the due payment when upgrading to a more costly plan